# Why only partial of Australia shown on the page --GeoJson

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, geojson

I loaded the GeoJson file from this link https://github.com/codeforamerica/click_that_hood/blob/master/public/data/australia.geojson, why just partial of it shown? How to debug it?

[image]

here is the code:

```
var width = 600,
height = 400;

var projection = d3.geoAlbers()
    .scale(200)
    .translate([width, height])

var path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)

    d3.json("data/aus.json").then(data=>{
        svg.selectAll('path')
        .data(data.features)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', path)
        .attr('stroke', '#fff')
        .attr('stroke-width', 1)
        .attr('fill','orange')
    })
```

Comment: It's not partial, all of Australia is there. It's just turned on its side and squished. Turn your head 90 degrees and see.

Comment: You need to rotate and set parallels for an Albers projection. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39958471/7106086)

Comment: I like the West Tasmania.